# Is there a better way to do this with promises?

Tags: javascript

I used the code below for years when I want to open a window and check when an specific element becomes present in the DOM of the opened window. It works fine, never had a problem. PS: assume jQuery is already imported into this project.

```
openedWindow = window.open("http://localhost/teste1.php");

myClock = window.setInterval(

    function() {

        if ($(openedWindow.window.document).find("#myElement").length == 1) {

            window.clearInterval(openedWindow);

            //DO MY STUFF HERE.

        }

    },
    100

);
```

So yesterday a friend of mine came to me, saw this code and said "You should do that with promises". He said he didnt know how promises worked in depth but he said my code would get smaller and easier to read.

Ok. I dont know promises too. So I studied for over an hour and came up with the code below that works "fine". Except it's a lot bigger and I cant find it easier to read at all.

```
new Promise(function(resolve,reject) {

    openedWindow = window.open("http://localhost/teste1.php");

    window.setInterval(

        function() {

            window.clearInterval(openedWindow);

            if ($(openedWindow.window.document).find("#myElement").length == 1) {

                resolve(true);

            }

        },
        100

    );

}).then(

    function(result) {

        if (result) {

            //DO MY STUFF HERE.

        }

    }

);
```

So was my friend wrong? Or I am the wrong one doing the wrong thing with prommises? Is there a better way to do that with promises that I, a newbie in this subject, and not seeing?

Comment: You should actually do that with mutation observers.

Comment: Your promise approach seems fine. You shouldn't need to `if(result)` since it is always going to be true if you resolve it with `true`. As for code getting smaller, no it won't in this case. In your initial approach you could just as easily call a function at same point you call `resolve()` in promise approach

Comment: @Jonas Wilms yeap, but I found the code to that is a lot complicated. But you are right!

Comment: @charlietfl thanks a lot! Your suggestion shaved out 4 lines :) I was not thinking straight, indeed when "then" is called it must have been because it resolved, so no need to check true! Thanks man.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### Disclamer:

I will leave my answer since I believe it is useful in the context of understanding Promises. The question is related to wait for stuff in the DOM, but I believe OP's main concern is to understand why one would use a Promise over a callback.

However, said so, for the specific problem related to react to DOM changes, [Nino's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55549534/4166367) is the best.

#### Original answer

> Except it's a lot bigger and I cant find it easier to read at all.

Well, the idea I think is that:

1. You expose a function like `waitForElement` which takes an `element` and returns a Promise that resolves when the element is found.
2. Now any part of your code can use this function to get a Promise of `element` being found. This is important because you can attach callbacks to already resolved Promises and still get it run (this is important if you're using a Promise that waits for a database connection, for instance).

So your function would be something like:

```
function waitForElement(element){
 return new Promise(function(resolve) {
    // maybe uri could be a param too
    openedWindow = window.open("http://localhost/teste1.php");

    window.setInterval(

        function() {

            window.clearInterval(openedWindow);

            if ($(openedWindow.window.document).find(element).length == 1) {
                resolve(true);
            }
        },
        100
    );
});
}
```

Note the `return` at the beginning of the method. So now any part of your code could call:

```
waitForElement('#foo').then( // do my stuff //);
```

This is still pretty much the same, as you say. However, a good thing about promises is that them allow to attach callbacks, and they cache the async operations, so now you can:

```
const fooIsPresent = waitForElement('#foo');

// later in your code
fooIsPresent( // some stuff //);

// and even later, maybe minutes later:
fooIsPresent(// still more stuff //);
```

Now, if the element still is not present, the stuff callbacks will be invoked when the moment arrives.

However, if the **element was already found**, and you call `fooIsPresent` after that, the callback will be executed *immediately* (in the next tick).

And if you want some stuff to always happen before another, you can chain them:

```
fooIsPresent.then(// first stuff //)
.then(// second stuff //);
```

So yes, the code is bigger and maybe a bit less clear, but now is more useful and you can use it in some handy ways.

Answer (score 2):

I agree with your assessment; your Promises version is longer and adds no clarity. Some people think that Promises make all code better, which is just untrue. You can have well-written or poorly-written code, irrespective of whether or not you use Promises. I personally find that clarity is often lost with Promises.

In the first example, I think you meant to pass `myClock` to `clearInterval()`. Anyway, I prefer to use `setTimeout` when I think it will probably be canceled shortly.

I like having a self-contained structure.

```
(function checker(openedWindow) {
  if (openedWindow.window.document.querySelector("#myElement")) {
    doMyStuff(openedWindow);
  } else {
    setTimeout(checker, 100, openedWindow);
  }
})(window.open("http://localhost/teste1.php"));

function doMyStuff(openedWindow) {
  // DO MY STUFF
}
```

Comment: Thanks for our attention. I just think your code would open several windows because everytime it checks if the element #myElement exists, if it does not, it will open a new window. Your recursive is a good idea but I think window.open should be left out of that function, right?

Comment: Yes, you're right. I'll update to pass the window in as an argument.

Answer (score 2):

You're both wrong but you're a bit more wrong than him because writing this code as promise allow you to compartiment your code better:

```js
/* without promises */
// code for waiting for an element to appear
// code for after
// code for waiting for an element to appear

/* with promises */
// code for waiting for an element to appear
// code for after
```

But yeah, you're both wrong because the modern way to wait for an element to appear is to use [mutation observers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver):

```js
const observer = new MutationObserver(mutationRecordList => {
  for (mutationRecord of mutationRecordList) {
    if (mutationRecord.target.getAttribute('id')=='#my-element') {
      console.log('The element just appeared');
    }
  }
});
observer.observe(document.body, {childList: true, subtree: true});
```

and wrap the whole thing as a promise, depending on your code.

Comment: Your code is a lot cleaner and small :) But I found it to be the most confusing of anything posted in this thread. But I am pretty sure your code is probably the optimal solution to a usecase similar to what I posted. But I really wanted to know if my promise code was wrong and could be improved using same logic (setInterval/setTimeout).

Comment: It's cleaner if you use the `.id` property instead of `.getAttribute()`... and you'll need to remove the `#` from the ID. That's just for selectors. Nice approach, though I think you'd want to `.disconnect()` since this seems to be needed only for the single element.